# subset lists based on a condition in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like:

```
df = read.table(text="S00001    S00002  S00003  S00004  S00005  S00006  
GG  AA  GG  AA  GG  AG  
CC  TT  TT  TC  TC  TT  
TT  CC  CC  TT  TT  TT  
AA  AA  GG  AA  AG  AA  
TT  CC  CC  TT  TC  TT  
GG  GG  GG  AA  GG  GG", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to count the number of character strings with the same letters (i.e. "AA", "CC", "GG", or "TT") for each row. What I did is to use table() function to count all elements and generated another list based on if the names of lists are "homo". I tried to subset the lists but it didn't work. Here is my scripts:

```
A <- apply(df,1, function(x) table(x))
B <- apply(df,1, function(x) (names(table(x)) %in% c("AA","CC","GG","TT")))
A[B] ## this didn't work
```

I expect a data frame would be generated:

```
2 3
1 3
2 4
4 1
2 3
1 5
```

appreciate any helps.

Comment: Do you always know in advance that `c("AA","CC","GG","TT")` are your only option for double letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do this with a single `apply`

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {tbl <- table(x)
        tbl[names(tbl) %in% c("AA", "CC", "GG", "TT")]}))
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    3
#[2,]    1    3
#[3,]    2    4
#[4,]    4    1
#[5,]    2    3
#[6,]    1    5
```

Comment: I have a problem with my real data. I would like to add two columns to the original df to hold the output from your script. I used `df[c("A","B")] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {tbl <- table(x)
                            tbl[names(tbl) %in% c("AA", "CC", "GG", "TT")]}))` but an error appeared "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, c("A", "B"), value = list(c(8L, 635L : 
  replacement element 1 has 2 rows, need 705". My data structure is the same as the example here. when I just checked the output of your script, the result looks like: '  X7     X9    X11      
[1,] Integer,2 Integer,2 Integer,2'

Comment: @user3354212  One possible reason is that there might not be "AA" (or "CC", "GG", "TT") in a particular row while it is present in another creating an imbalance in the number of elements in the output.  We can do `v1 <- c("AA", "CC", "GG", "TT"); t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {table(factor(x[x%in%v1], levels=v1))}))`

Comment: I found the issue. few rows in my real data has only one double letter (i.e only one element, not two different double letter elements). So I have to remove those rows first by `lapply(B, function(x) length(x) > 1)` and then apply your script. That should work.

Answer (score 4):

Try `mapply`. It will take each element of the lists sequentially for evaluation. The header names are auto-generated, you can change them as you see fit:

```
t(mapply('[', A, B))
     AA GG
[1,]  2  3
[2,]  1  3
[3,]  2  4
[4,]  4  1
[5,]  2  3
[6,]  1  5
```

As mentioned by CathG, you can avoid calculating `B` with:

```
t(sapply(A, function(x){x[grepl("([A-Z])\\1", names(x))]}))
```

Comment: `t(sapply(A, function(x){x[names(x) %in% c("AA","CC","GG","TT")]}))` would give the same, without having to compute `B`

Comment: @CathG I noticed that. I added as way to show OP how to use a function over two lists

Comment: or  `t(sapply(A, function(x){x[grepl("([A-Z])\\1", names(x))]}))`

Comment: I will add for posterity :)

Comment: @CathG it's a nice one

Answer (score 3):

I don't like `apply` due to matrix conversion and especially `apply(df, 1,...)` due to by row operations.

Alternatively, I would suggest and helper function that uses `sapply` combined with `rowSums` (which will operate on `sapply` matrix output)

```
f <- function(x, y) rowSums(sapply(x, `%in%`, y))
```

then you could do (without calculating `A` and `B`)

```
cbind(f(df, c("AA", "CC")), 
      f(df, c("GG", "TT")))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    3
# [2,]    1    3
# [3,]    2    4
# [4,]    4    1
# [5,]    2    3
# [6,]    1    5
```

Or just (depends on what you looking for)

```
f(df, c("AA", "CC", "GG", "TT"))
# [1] 5 4 6 5 5 6
```

Comment: my real data are not just ("A", "G") or ("C", "T") combinations for each row. They may be any two combinations from the four letters, in a format of two unique double letters, maybe one mixed letters. for example ("AA", "CC", and/or "AC" ) in some rows. So the output results from your script for ("A","C") or ("G","T") are not what I expected.

Comment: This solution will work correctly as per description of your problem + the solution you were attempting, try `f(df, "TC")` for example. If you have some special case that you failed to mention and you are looking for a regex solution, you should have mention that and show your desired result for such cases too. And don't get me started with downvotes because you failed to provide a MWE after I spend my time helping you for free.

Comment: Sorry my comments make you upset. Your script works fine with the example. Sorry I didn't include all possible combinations of my data in my example. if my "df" like this:df = read.table(text="AA  AA  CC  AA  AC  AA  
TT  GG  GG  TT  TG  TT", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F), the expected result is (4,1), (3,3). Thank you for your time.

Comment: You have a data set with only one row?

Comment: this should be two rows: "AA AA CC AA AC AA"  "TT GG GG TT TG TT"

Comment: Then you can do `cbind(f(df, c("AA", "GG")), f(df, c("CC", "TT")))`, though your two columns desired output doesn't make much sense to me as you don't really know what each value means.